# How can I add values from a datagridview into a pie chart in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, charts, datagridview, pie-chart

I would like to represent 2 values from a datagridview into a pie chart. These values are integers and have already been displayed in the datagridview. I just need those values to be displayed in a pie chart.
Here is what I've tried:

```
    For Count As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
        Chart1.Series(0).Points.Add(DataGridView1.Item(0, Count).Value, DataGridView1.Item(1, Count).Value)
        Chart1.Series(1).Points.Add(DataGridView1.Item(0, Count).Value, DataGridView1.Item(1, Count).Value)
    Next
```

This creates a loop to insert all values from the datagridview into the chart. The problem is that when it runs, the chart does **not** display these two integers.

Comment: Since VBA doesnt have datagridview controls, you must mean VB.NET

Comment: Can you display hard-coded data in a pie chart? If not, that should be the first thing you try, rather than involving a `DataGridView`. If you can then the issue would appear to be getting the data out of the grid, so you should be doing that in isolation without the chart. This is how software development works. When things go wrong, the first thing YOU do is work out what part isn't working. If you're asking us about a grid and a chart then you haven't done enough to isolate the issue yet.

Comment: If you are not getting an error in the posted code, then something else is going on. Even though it appears you may be missing the last row and both series have the same values… the code appears to work as expected. Are you sure this code is getting executed? Put a break point at the beginning of the loop and trace what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Declare the x and y values and the series of the pie chart.

   ```
   Dim series As String = "Time"
   Dim yval As Double() = { x, y }
   Dim xval As String() = {"Time Studying", "Time Not Studying"}
   ```
2. Retrieve the values from the data grid view.

   ```
   For Count As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
       x = DataGridView1.Item(0, Count).Value
       y = DataGridView1.Item(1, Count).Value
   Next
   ```
3. Clear the graph values

   ```
    Chart1.Series.Clear()
    Chart1.Titles.Clear()
   ```
4. Plot values into chart.

   ```
   Chart1.Series.Add(series)
   Chart1.Series(series).Points.DataBindXY(xval, yval)
   Chart1.Series("Time").IsValueShownAsLabel = True
   Chart1.Series(series).Points(0).Color = Color.LightSkyBlue
   Chart1.Series(series).Points(1).Color = Color.Orange
   Chart1.Series(series).ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to get the id of the selected item in the Datagridview first, and use a datable for  its record to display in chart, that should do the trick